# How can I add an IsTrigger propriety from code? Unity

Tags: unity

I made an gameobject in my script and i made it a rigidbody, and added it a boxcollider, but I dont know how to tell the program to make it a trigger. Here's my code until now:

```
multi = new GameObject();
                multi.AddComponent<Transform>();
                multi.transform.position = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
                multi.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                multi.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `BoxCollider2D` in a variable then access `isTrigger` property from that.

You can do something like,

```
BoxCollider2D bc = multi.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
bc.isTrigger = true;
```

By the way, there is no need to add `Transform` explicitly as `Transform` is a basic property of any world object to handle transformation (translation, rotation, scaling).